# React/JS: how to pass html element via function?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

```
const list_item = (key,str) => <li key={key}>{str}</li>
```

and, in my render func,

```
<li key={mykey}> {mystring} <MdCheckCircle /> </li>
```

When I place the list_item function in the render method, however, I cannot add `<MdCheckCircle/>`:

```
list_item(mykey,mystring + "<MdCheckCircle/>")
// renders as string literal on the site

list_item(mykey,mystring + <MdCheckCircle/>) 
// renders as "[ Object ]" on the site
```

How do I pass this html element such that it renders properly?

Comment: Can't you have `<li key={mykey}> {mystring} <MdCheckCircle /> </li>` as a separate component and pass in `mykey` and `mystring` as props? Can you show all your render function for context?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes, except now my function granularity is too high.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney asked this specifically to avoid writing that more specific func

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass component direct into function like  as another parameter

```
const list_item = (key, str, comp) => <li key={key}>{str} {comp}</li>;

const MdCheckCircle = () => <div>Circle</div>;

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{list_item(1, "string", <MdCheckCircle />)}</div>;
    }
}
```